# check for className before running the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

How can I achieve this?

for each pages I have attached a unique class-name so I can target them by css later.

- body.**pageHome**
- about.**pageAbout**
- contact.**pageContact**

I want to run a function but only targeting the homepage.

eg.

```
if($('body').hasClass('pageHome')) {
 callMe;
}

function callMe() {
 alert('I am Home!');
}
```

Comment: Change callMe to callMe() inside the if condition.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, Yes I missed it...

Comment: It happens.. Please check your error console for any script errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're close.  To call `callMe`, you'll want parenthesis to indicate that it's a function call:

```
if($('body').hasClass('pageHome')) {
 callMe();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your forgot the parenthesis when you called `callMe`:

```
function callMe() {
    alert('I am Home!');
}
if($('body').hasClass('pageHome')) {
    callMe();
}
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Concept should work fine as long as you are wrapping code in

```
$(function(){  /* run code*/ })
```

and you need to add "()" to callme();